# Read a string from a point

Tags: string, winforms, colors

Truth is, I don't know if I asked the question correctly, but here is the explanation:
I created a texbox that works as a command line. You enter data and depending on what is written, it will perform several functions: for example: change the color of a panel, button, letter, etc.

Now I try that when I enter "color.Red" the program detects the word "color" and then knows that all that appears after that word is the color that the user wants to change so far it is like this:

```
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) // if user presses enter
        {
            System.Drawing.Color myColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml (command_txt.Text); // reads the content of the textbox and passes it to html language that gives us the color
            this.BackColor = myColor; // at the end, set this color to the bottom of the form
        }
```

As you can see, I only made the program able to read the color.
Is there a way to run this code only when the user enters "color" + "(whatever color you want)".?

Comment: I believe that you will need to implement a `parser`, because as far I known there is no built-in function that do what you want. Take your [first steps in parser here](https://medium.com/the-mighty-programmer/what-is-parsing-4012f997d265) and [check this library after](https://fclp.github.io/fluent-command-line-parser/).

Comment: `string color = "color:red"; var c = Color.FromName(color.Split(':')[1]);` (if `color.Split(':')[0]` is `"color"` - invariant ignore case).

Comment: You should probably have a Parser for your *language* that determines what action to take based on the value of the left-hand key. -- To simplify, you could build a `Dictionary<string, Func<string, TResult>)>` to automate the conversions.